# JQuery UI MVC3 - Mapping of Downloaded ZIP and Already existing files(css, .js, images)

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using ASP.NET MVC3. Adding a web project, it gives me all the files required for jquery to run.

It gives me Content Folder and some folders for storing css and Images.

It also gives me Scripts folder, where I can have my .js files.

Whenever I want to download some custom JQUERY UI controls, It gives me a zip file which has different folders and scripts.

How do I map them so that, I am not keeping too many jquery files in my project.

For example, I want to use DatePicker Jquery UI, I go to jquery site and download them and it gives me a ZIP File which has various folders.

There is folder called development again it has got all the files.

If I wan to go for timepicker, I think there is only a CSS difference between timepicker and datepicker.

Timepicker needs slider. So I am not sure do i need to reference jqueryslider.js in my Layouts file.

Please shed some light on this mapping of downloaded files and already existing files in MVc3?

if have to include new Jquery UI Control, What should be the changes, is it just in .js file, images folder, or css folder.

I personally think its only css and images, please correct me.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add the content in the js folder to the scripts in your *Scripts* folder and copy everything from the css\\ folder into the *Content* folder of your MVC application.

Once you have done this, you simply add the following references to the _Layout file in your Shared folder (just modify to match your version of JQuery and the correct version of your JQuery-UI download):

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Just remember to keep the reference to your JQuery library (jquery-1.7.1.min.js in the example above) before the reference to the JQueryUI scripts.

-- Kindly mark as the answer if this has been helpful